# The same default value gets used every time by `new mongoose.Schema`

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have problem using `uuid` with `new mongoose.Schema`. I use it to generate unique key for a device and save it to the MongoDb using Node.js. the problem is that it uses the same UUID every time.

This is the model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

const DeviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    deviceNumberHash: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    receivingKey: {
        type: String,
        default: uuid()
    }...
});
```

And this is what is saved in MongoDb:
[image]

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're **calling** `uuid` and passing its return value in as the default to use.

Instead, pass in the **function** (by not putting `()` after it):

```
const DeviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    deviceNumberHash: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    receivingKey: {
        type: String,
        default: uuid // <========== No ()
    }...
});
```

The default can be a function [per the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition) (an example there uses `default: Date.now` to provide a default for a date field, for instance).